# Is there a way to get the project file in Visual Studio to save automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Whenever we add or delete files from our project, it requires to also hit 'save all' so that the project file will copy these changes. Is there some preference or plugin that we can use that will make sure the project file gets updated at the same time?

We run into issues where someone will add/remove a file and forget to hit save all which causes issues once it is pushed to git.

Comment: Hit <ctrl>+<shift>+S every one minute. New feature in VS'97 --- or https://www.google.com/#q=visual+studio+2015+autosave or https://www.google.com/#q=visual+studio+autosave or http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/configure-autosave-autorecovery-of-crashed-projects-in-visual-studio-2005/

Comment: Also note that VS saves the project when you build by default, so unless you are adding files but not compiling, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Interesting.  Here, where we use AnkhSVN, I have never noticed a problem with the project files (.vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters) but definitely with a .props file.  If you thnk it's difficult to get Visual Studio to save your project, it's darned near impossible to get it to save a properties file!  By the way, I agree with your complaint, Sako.  It should really save these things automatically and never bite us in the rear.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are tools (i.e. [Is there a visual studio automatic save configuration setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979561/is-there-a-visual-studio-automatic-save-configuration-setting-addon) as pointed in comments)...

In real life usage when people run unit tests before checking in (or at least build) it is not needed as projects are saved before build.